# Releasing a bitmap attached to an ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a basic activity (SherlockActivity subclass), and the view it loads has a single, max-sized ImageView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ImageView
        p1:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/imageView"
        p1:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The only thing the Activity does is load a Bitmap and assign it to the ImageView

```
var iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
iv.SetBitmapImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file....))
```

Before I worked out how to resize bitmaps on load ( http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html ) this was chewing up 5MB of memory each time I loaded the activity, until the app crashed (now it doesn't, but I think this problem is still there). Even if I did it like this:

- In parent activity, tap button to open child
- In child (the above image view) tap back
- In parent, open child
- In child, tap back
- etc etc. until it crashes (about 4 times around, as it's 5MB each time!)

**SO THE ACTUAL QUESTION: Am I expected to dispose of the image when the Activity stops or is destroyed? I thought in Java - or C# - things are GC'ed, so I don't need to do it. Am I missing something in the Activity lifecycle?**

**Both answer authors eventually came up with the right answer (the GC does it, but you can force it with recycle(). So marking correct the one which had it in the answer, so it's easier to find for others**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling `recycle()` on the bitmap.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29

Comment: Yeah, thats option #2. I was mostly wondering if I actually NEED to do this, or if the GC just cleans it up (maybe it didn't have time to clean it up?)

Comment: Yeah, all the docs I've found so far say "call it if you want, but the GC will do it for you anyway"....

Comment: @NicWise, the only doc is the official doc. What doce are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Loading large bitmaps can cause OutOfMemoryError. You can scale down the image before loading it in your app; that will consume less memory. You may look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13011614/1117338

Comment: Thanks, but as I said: I worked this bit out already. This is only about "do I need to release the bitmap".

Comment: You can set the bitmap to null when you have finished working with it. It will dereference it from the memory.

Comment: that was kind of the answer I was after: the GC _does_ clean it up. Well, in theory :) I'll keep a handle to the bitmap and release it onStop. Thanks!