# How to remove unused Image Views in Xamarin due to Out of memory exception?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, out-of-memory

So I have an issue. I am displaying images from the resources folder and each time there's an out of memory exception.

I scoured StackOverflow and the web for hours and none of the suggestions worked.

When I do:

```
    if (myview != null){ 
    myview.Dispose();
    myview = new ImageView();
    }
    return myview;
```

I get an error saying child already has a parent and I should call removeview(). When I do that, it results in a null reference exception.

I'm confused. Please help!

EDIT: I am not displaying bitmaps, but am using images in the jpeg and png file type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Releasing a bitmap attached to an ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027209/releasing-a-bitmap-attached-to-an-imageview)

Comment: @SushiHangover I am not displaying bitmaps. The images are in jpeg and png form

Answer (score 1):

The type of image does not matter,  you are asking about releasing the memory of an image within an ImageView.

Either:

1) Unparent the view from the parent to completely *remove* the visual control.

```
ImageView myImageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.myImageView);
(myImageView.Parent as IViewManager).RemoveView(myImageView);
```

2) Clear the image (bitmap) from the `ImageView`:

```
ImageView myImageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.myImageView);
myImageView.SetImageResource(0);
```

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your answer. In actual fact, I am using an ImageSwitcher to display Images, so I am having issues trying to set the image resource to null because I need to create a new Instance each time in the MakeView() procedure for the IViewFactory

Comment: @Vishwas Then remove the `ImageView` that was created from its a parent , option 1 in my answer.

Comment: Now I have System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error on the removeview line